# Use rake namespace as configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, rake

I am trying to create a rake file with tasks for consuming my API. I want to be able and pass a lot of arguments to the task, depending on the call to be used. In an effort to make the tasks easier to use, I want the namespace to be part of the configuration. Is this possible?

```
namespace :myAPI do

    SERVER = 'local'
    namespace :live do
        SERVER = 'live'
    end
    namespace :beta do
        SERVER = 'beta'
    end

    BASE_URI = {
        live: "https://myapi.com/do/v1",
        beta: "https://beta.myapi.com/do/v1",
        local: "http://127.0.0.1:4500/do/v1"
    }

    desc 'Get currently logged users'
    task :extract_logged_users => :environment do
        get("BASE_URI[SERVER]/users/current")
    end

}
```

And then I want to be able and run this against the live server for example:

```
rake myAPI:live:extract_logged_users
```

Comment: Well, if written this way, the task `extract_logged_users` is still defined only in the `myAPI` namespace. Furthermore this way you are redefining the `SERVER` constant multiple times (and rake gives a warning).

Comment: Perhaps you can define your tasks in the main `myAPI` namespace and then dynamically define the same ones in all the sub-namespaces. These dynamic tasks would only set the needed variables and would call `invoke("myAPI:the_task")` i.e. the task in the main namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the task in a mor dynamic way like this:

```
require 'rake'
BASE_URI = {
    live: "https://myapi.com/do/v1",
    beta: "https://beta.myapi.com/do/v1",
    local: "http://127.0.0.1:4500/do/v1"
}.each do |server,url|
  namespace :myAPI do
    namespace server do |ns|
      desc 'Get currently logged users'
      task :extract_logged_users do
          puts 'get("%s/users/current", %s)' % [server,url]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(I replaced your get command with `puts` to check what happens and added the url into the command).

Now you can call:

```
rake myAPI:live:extract_logged_users
rake myAPI:beta:extract_logged_users
rake myAPI:local:extract_logged_users
```

The output:

```
get("live/users/current", https://myapi.com/do/v1)
get("beta/users/current", https://beta.myapi.com/do/v1)
get("local/users/current", http://127.0.0.1:4500/do/v1)
```

---

Alternative coding:

```
namespace :myAPI do

    BASE_URI = {
        live: "https://myapi.com/do/v1",
        beta: "https://beta.myapi.com/do/v1",
        local: "http://127.0.0.1:4500/do/v1"
    }

    BASE_URI .keys.each do |key|
      namespace key do |ns|
        desc 'Get currently logged users'
        task :extract_logged_users do
           puts 'get("%s")' % BASE_URI[key]
        end
      end
  end
end
```